# Agregar checkbox y obtener los checkbox seleccionados de un Modal

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap, typescript, checkbox

Hola a todos estoy trabajando con Angular, y Bootstrap 4.

**1.-** Tengo el siguiente modal y quisiera que al agregar la información dinámicamente, agregue algunos checkbox ya seleccionados y otros no, eso dependiendo de la configuración, por ahora lo estoy llenando con un array de objetos, pero quisiera saber qué tendría que hacer para llenarlo con algunos check seleccionados y otros no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**2.-** En el Modal puedo seleccionar o deseleccionar los checkbox y cuando le de a Save changes obtenga el id de los checkbox que fueron modificados, tanto los seleccionados como los deseleccionados.

Mis ckecbox ya tienen un value para identificarlos, solo que no sé cómo sacar todos los check modificados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les comparto el proyecto para que me apoyen a orientarme a cómo podría solucionar estos inconvenientes que tengo

[https://codesandbox.io/checkbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-3sjvp?file=/src/app/app.component.html)

De antemano muchas gracias por su apoyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo de esta manera:

Primero modificas el select de esta manera:

```
<input 
     (change)="revisarCambio(obtenerClave(servicio, subServicio))" 
     type="checkbox" 
/>
```

En tu `component.ts` agregas esto

```
/**
   * Obtiene el nombre para el objeto seleccionados
   * @param servicio
   * @param subservicio
   */
  obtenerClave(servicio, subservicio): string {
    return servicio.nombreServicio +'$'+ subservicio.idServicio;
  }
  //Aqui guardamos las referencias 
  seleccionados = {};
  //Asigamos le cambio al objeto `seleccionados`
  revisarCambio(clave) {
    //Esto es para que no de error si no existe la propiedad
    if (!this.seleccionados[clave]) this.seleccionados[clave] = false;
    //Esto invierte la seleccion actual. 
    this.seleccionados[clave] = !this.seleccionados[clave];
  }
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahh99f)

Comment: Excelente amigo, muchas gracias por el apoyo. funciona bien.